# How do I import 400+ modules, and iterate over them in my angular-cli project?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular-cli, jsdata

I am about to have 400+ models for use with js-data in my angular2 (angular-cli) app.

my project's structure is this:

```
- src/
  - app/
    - services/
    - pipes/
    - ui/
    - data/
      - store.ts
      - models/
        - model1.ts
        - model2.ts
        - ...
        - model400.ts
```

In the store, I need to import, and add the mapping to the store. 
The model files are actually just mapper configs for js-data 3.

currently, they look something like this:

```
// src/app/data/models/model1.ts
export default {
  schema: {
    name: 'model1',
    properties: { 
      id: { type: 'integer' }
    }
  },
  relations: {}
}
```

and my store currently looks like this:

```
// src/app/data/store.ts
import {
  DataStore,
  Mapper,
  Record,
  Schema,
  utils
} from 'js-data'
import {HttpAdapter} from 'js-data-http'

declare var require: any

export const adapter = new HttpAdapter({
  // Our API sits behind the /api path
  basePath: '/api'
});

export const store = new DataStore({});
store.registerAdapter('http', adapter, { default: true });

import { model1Config} from './models/model1';
import { model2Config } from './models/model2';
import { model3Config } from './models/model3';
// at this point, I give up, cause this is more tedious 
// than cutting grass with a finger nail clipper
store.defineMapper('model1', model1Config);
store.defineMapper('model2', model2Config);
store.defineMapper('model3', model3Config);
```

If there is anyway to iterate over every file in the models folder, that would be great.

angular-cli is supposed to eventually compile all the ts/js to a single js file, so I don't need to worry about anything that couldn't run on the client side.
(so, I have broccoli, and whatever other build tools are bundled with that, I just don't know if any of them would be useful to me for this situation)

Answer (score 2):

You could use an index file, which you can use for your imports. for example in your `models` folder an index file which just exports every model for you like this:

```
// ...../models/index.ts

export * from './models/model1';
export * from './models/model2';
```

then in your other files you can import them like this:

```
import {model1Config, model2Config, model3Config } from "path/to/models/index";
...
```

You have to define the exports somewhere. Using a file which functions as a "export collection" saves you at least a lot lines of code (and a lot of time if you're using a good IDE).
Setting up the the index with your x-hundreds of models still is tedious. Maybe a little script with gulp could help.

Comment: I'm only really importing the files once to configure the store. So, I don't need this level of importability. This is good to know though!

Comment: Mh, can't think of anything that could help you get rid of the `store.defineMapper` calls. Except of generating the file or this snippet somehow.

Comment: yeah, someone in the js-data slack channel suggested writing a t4 script in visual studio (since the backend is .net) - it would at least help get started, but maintaining 800+ lines of importing the configs and setting mapper on the store is just unacceptable, imo.

Comment: the created of js-data suggested to just generate the store file -- which I could do, I just don't know how. I *think* it would maybe be a broccoli step? which takes a store.ts.gen file or whatever, and expands some for loop? idk.

Comment: have to raise the white flag here. never worked with broccoli. But well, generating a file which just adds some links depending of files found in a folder shouldn't be so hard. you probably can do it in any language. it should be part of your build process of course.